# Close Dialogs once its main dialog is closed

Tags: c++, qt5

I have Main Dialog which has some buttons. Each button will generate an independent dialog as follows:

```
void MainDialog::onAButtonClicked()
{
     Dialog *dial = new Dialog(pass some parameters);
     dial->show();
}
```

The problem with this approach is when the user closes the Main Dialog, the running independent dialog is not closed. I don't want this issue to occur. Some solutions suggest to override `closeEvent` and `reject`, I've tried them but these require me to create `*dial` as a member data of Main Dialog. This works but I don't want this approach because I need to delete this dialog once the user closes the window completely. I've tried to allocate some memory using `new` and delete object on `close` or `reject` events but the app hangs. What is the proper approach to solve this issue?

Comment: Feel free for any queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
connect(this,SIGNAL(finished(int)),dial,SLOT(close()));
```

or

```
connect(this,SIGNAL(rejected()),dial,SLOT(close()));
```

Comment: I don't want `dial` to be a member data of the Main Dialog. I would like to completely avoid this approach. The user can click the button several times while some previous dialogs are running already as long as the Main Dialog is running.

Comment: `dial` here is not a member of Main Dialog. Here we just connect a signal from Main Dialog to slot of `dial`.